# Porblema al cargar pagina de login codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

No me muestra al entrar con el login

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: [if($this->Login_Model->checkUsers($email,$password = null)){
    
    $data = $this->Login_Model->checkUsers($email,$password);
    
    print_r($data);
   }]

Comment: Cuando hagas una pregunta en Stack Overflow, deberías incluir el código para comprobar el error. Lo más probable en tu caso es que no hayas cargado el modelo o que éste tenga otro nombre distinto a Login_Model.

Comment: ok. Lo cambio..